# rails polymorphic with includes different association based on type of class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, eager-loading

my question is how to include different association depend on class type when polymophic.
below is example.

```rb
class History
  belongs_to :history_able, polymorphic: true
end

class ReviewHistory
  has_many :histories, as: :history_able
  has_many :reviews
end

class InterviewHistory
  has_many :histories, as: :history_able
  has_many :interviews
end

class Review
  belongs_to :review_history
end

class Interview
  belongs_to :interview_history
end
```

I want to eager load different model based on history_type.
for example, when History is ReviewHistory type, then include reviews, when History is InterviewHistory then include interviews.

please let me know if there is good tip for this situation.